# as3 URLLoader Cache suggestions for mobile app

Tags: android, ios, actionscript-3

I have been looking around for a class to manage the caching of the data from a URLLoader call but been unsuccessful. Does URLLoader cache by default?

I am building an app that fetches a bunch of information on the user (profile details, friend lists, profile image etc) and I would prefer not to call URLLoader each time. I am caching their profile image on first load and hope I can do the same with the rest of the data without having to create a clone of the DB locally.

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the URLLoader caches requests, and there are various solutions to break that cache request (generally by adding a random element to the end of the web request). You can see the [documentation here for the URLRequest object](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/URLRequest.html#cacheResponse) that's returned, and it's various cache options.

However, I recommend persisting the data locally upon receiving the request and using the platform's database / data storage pattern that you're on. Then, check for internet prior to making the request: if you can make a connection, make the request to retrieve and update the local data. If there's no internet / connection, just load the data you have saved locally. Using the "cached" version of the request isn't a trustworthy pattern.

Comment: So you think it would be best to create a local DB to save the remote data then update if internet connection or at a particular interval OR if the user initiates a refresh request?

Comment: Yes, it's best to persist the data locally and retrieve it there if there is no internet. Update on user request, or interval, or at specific events (i.e. user loads a new view, check for internet, retrieve data or retrieve cache). Don't rely on http cache; persist your own in the local database. Match the data model of whatever the service is providing to your local database model. It's worth it.